How to retrieve photos from recovered files?
Linux noob here. I used photorec to recover some photos and documents from an external hard disk I accidentally formatted. I was able to recover all of it, it looks like, however the files recovered are all names recup_dir and I am not sure how do I get the photos and documents off these folders and files.
What is the best course of action here? Do the file names indicate that the files have gone corrupt and irretrievable?



I understand what the letters in the filenames stand for but I'm having a tough time navigating the Testdisk documentation. Is there a way I can retrieve the docs and photos off these files?
I'm using a laptop running Debian

They'll be inside the recup_dir folders, with an appropriate extension (jpg etc). I have a script laying around from when I used to work on dead drives that I should be able to pull up if you want, that will sort files on a photorec base directory based on the recovered files' extension, isolating very small .jpg files in the process (as those are usually thumbnails). It's very I ugly and I wrote it when I barely knew what Bash was but it works. Anyways again, the files are there, just searching ,jpg in the base directory should suffice to see them.

If photos more info here. Use scripts to help sort and rename files:
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/After_Using_PhotoRec
use flac tags to rename files
http://lglinux.blogspot.com/2008/10/use-flac-tags-to-rename-files.html
I once recovered some text files. Had to compare many recovered copies with old backup, took long time & taught me to have better backups.
